# How to a SOAP XML service PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I am completly new to SOAP.

I have been provided with an XML document (SOAP) to send data and receive response.

here is the xml document XML.

```
<OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"
TimeStamp="2004-05-01T06:39:09"
Target="Production"
Version="1.002">
  <AvailStatusMessages HotelCode="ATLPE" HotelName="The Sheraton">
  <AvailStatusMessage BookingLimit="25"
  BookingLimitMessageType="SetLimit">
  <StatusApplicationControl Start="2011-12-02"
  End="2011-12-05"
  RatePlanCode="WHLS1" InvCode="STD">
 </StatusApplicationControl>
<UniqueID Type="16" ID="1">
</UniqueID>
</AvailStatusMessage>
<AvailStatusMessage BookingLimit="35"
BookingLimitMessageType="SetLimit">
<!-- Content omitted -->
</AvailStatusMessage>
</AvailStatusMessages>
</OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQ>
```

WSDL file: https://rzbetal4.rategain.com/RZIntegration/Services/ARI/ARIEndPoint/RGBR/RGBridgeARI.wsdl

I need to bind the hotel_code and hotel_name,BookingLimit etc.. and send

How do i send using SOAP and receive a response

Any help would be highly great full.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to attach the wsdl file https://rzbetal4.rategain.com/RZIntegration/Services/ARI/ARIEndPoint/RGBR/RGBridgeARI.wsdl

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! You can edit your question to attach the .wsdl file within the question instead of in the comments. That would be better I think.

Comment: Thank you William Patton